# How to Authenticate Rest APIs which are integrated with SSO

Tags: c#, rest, api, authentication, single-sign-on

I'm trying to build a web application in asp.net MVC(C#) in which i will call jira rest APIs through basic authentication.But the base url of the rest api utilises SSO. How do I make the rest api call which is integrated with single sign on(SSO). We are using SAML protocol for SSO.

Im currently using basic Authentication with base 64 encoded single signon credentials. But I'm getting 401 Unauthenticated error.

Below is the code :

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);
                     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password))));
```

I'm able to call the rest apis in browser through single sign on credentials.

Comment: Please paste your code and show your effort so far.

Comment: I have edited my post with the code I tried